# How do I remove '\' characters from my NSString

Tags: objective-c

/images/content/booking_thumbs_uk/s_kl/50000/THB_999_H54007.jpg

changes to:

/images/content/booking_thumbs_uk/s_kl/00000/THB_999_H2470.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    NSString* original=@"\\/images\\/content\\/booking_thumbs_uk\\/s_kl\\/50000\\/THB_999_H54007.jpg";
    NSString* removed=[original stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@",removed);  // shows /images/content/booking_thumbs_uk/s_kl/00000/THB_999_H2470.jpg
```

Be very careful, because inside the source code between "..."  the backslash has a special meaning. In order to represent an honest backslash, you need to double it, like "\\".

Comment: lol was wondering what was going on - must have updated your post? works now thanks

Comment: I don't know what happened; my post got corrupted when I first posted it. It looked OK on the preview page. So I re-posted the same thing, which works now.  Strange.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `newString = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];`

Comment: also, look at the other functions in the "Replacing Substrings" section in the NSString documentation.

Comment: You need to double the backslash to represent one backslash. `@"\\"`.